# POST requests incomplete on Google script

Tags: curl, google-apps-script

I'm trying from a Google sheets to send a POST request using urlFetchApp.

I have written the code below but can make it work. Each time I run this script I have the following error - "code":400,"message":"Bad request: Incomplete token request". Which I don't understand because when I run the same request from POSTMAN, I have a succesful answer. In flied client id, I have special character like "/" and "+" and in client_secret "!", maybe it comes from there ?

Thanks for your help !

---- GSheets script -----

```
function DX_API_request() {
  var payload  = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': 'name/a+@b.com',
    'client_secret': 'XXX!'
  }; 
  var options = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload),
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(payload));
    var test = UrlFetchApp.getRequest('https ://dx-example.com/admin/v100/api/oauth/token', options);
    Logger.log(test);
    var resquest_bearer = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https ://dx-example.com/admin/v100/api/oauth/token',options);
    Logger.log(resquest_bearer);
    var dataAll = JSON.parse(resquest_bearer.getContentText());
    Logger.log(dataAll.message);
}
```

----- Curl command in Postman -------

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 655d9932-4681-f23d-6caf-5fcf63c10b82" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=name/a+@b.com&client_secret=XXX!' "https ://example.com/admin/v100/api/oauth/token"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not making the same request in google apps script as the curl command.

In the request made with curl you are setting the content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and also set two additional headers: `Cache-Control: no-cache` `Postman-Token: 655d9932-4681-f23d-6caf-5fcf63c10b82`

The same request in google script would be something like:

```
var payload = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': 'name/a+@b.com',
    'client_secret': 'XXX!'
};
var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': payload,
    'headers': {
        "Cache-Control": 'no-cache',
        "Postman-Token": '655d9932-4681-f23d-6caf-5fcf63c10b82'
    }
};
var test = UrlFetchApp.getRequest('https://dx-example.com/admin/v100/api/oauth/token', options);
Logger.log(test);
```

The main problem is probably that in you script is posting the data as `application/json` and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. More info here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app